# I am facing problem with the react browser router nesting?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, browser-refresh

So here i am usign two browser router nested and when i try to load it using link it works but when i try to refresh the page all content goes away and i can't get anything on screen.

Here is my main router and my sub router is inside AdminDashboard.

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={"/"} render={props => (
          <Login />
        )} />
        <Route exact path={"/registration"} render={props => (
          <Registration />
        )} />
        <Route exact path={"/admin/dashboard"} render={props => (
          <AdminDashboard />
        )} />
        <Route exact path={"/judge/dashboard"} render={props => (
          <JudgeDashboard />
        )} />
        <Route exact path={"/dashboard"} render={props => (
          <StudentDashboard />
        )} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
```

Here is my Admin Dashboard component code.

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <SideDrawer showSideDrawer={this.state.SideDrawerOpen}/>
      {backDrop}
      <Toolbar drawerClickHandler={this.drawerToggleHandler} SidebarOpen={this.state.SideDrawerOpen} title1={this.state.title}/>
      <main className="admin-main">
          <div>
            <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/admin/dashboard" render={()=><CompetitionList onchangeLocation={this.changeLocation}/>}/>
          <Route path="/admin/competitionDetails/:comp_id" component={CompetitionDetails} />
          <Route exact path="/admin/studentlist" render={()=><StudentList onchangeLocation={this.changeLocation}/>}/>
          <Route exact path="/admin/profile" render={()=><Profile onchangeLocation={this.changeLocation}/>}/>
          <Route exact path="/admin/judgelist" render={()=><JudgeList onchangeLocation={this.changeLocation}/>}/>
          <Route exact path="/admin/adminlist" render={()=><AdminList onchangeLocation={this.changeLocation}/>}/>
          <Route exact path="/admin/addcompetition" render={()=><AddCompetition onchangeLocation={this.changeLocation}/>} />
          <Route path="/admin/addcompetition/:comp_id" component={AddCompetition} />
          <Route exact path="/admin/addsurvey" render={()=><Survey onchangeLocation={this.changeLocation}/>} />
         </Switch>
          </div>
      </main>
      </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: which version of router are you using

Comment: main router should have /admin and then admin routes should have /admin/dashboard, /admin/profile and so on

Comment: I am using "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2"

Comment: I tried your Suggestion but it stops working for dashboard components also

Answer (score 0):

Would you try using NestedRouter?
For more idea follow this https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5291
Let me know if it works...